# Transitive models and CH

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Suppose $M, N$ are two countable transitive models of ZFC which have same ordinals, cofinalities and reals (but not necessarily same sets of reals!). Suppose $M$ models the continuum hypothesis. Can we conclude that $N$ also models continuum hypothesis? I can see that if this fails, then neither one of $M, N$ is included in the other. But what if $M, N$ are incomparable.

Comment: Monroe Eskew gave a talk about this in Madison (GSCL, 2014). Here's the reference (See his comments at the end of page 10) http://www.math.uci.edu/~meskew/densecard.pdf

Also http://www.math.uci.edu/~meskew/lsc2014.pdf

Answer (score 5):

This is possible. Let me first give a close result by Philipp Schlicht and myself, and then give the relevant result by Woodin.

> Let $V$ be the first Cohen model. Namely, add $\omega$ Cohen reals to $L$ and take the finitary permutations of $\omega$ applied to "switching" the reals, and all the sets definable from finitely many reals and the set of Cohen reals. Then $A$ is the set of Cohen reals is Dedekind-finite.
>
> If $\kappa$ is *any* infinite $\aleph$ cardinal, then forcing using finite injections from $A$ to $\kappa$ recovers choice and in fact gives us that $A$ is the generic filter for adding $\kappa$ Cohen reals over $L$. In particular no cofinalities were changed.

This is from a work in slow-progress. But it shows that you can have more Cohen reals by forgetting how to count them first, and then trying to count them in a different way. Our result, however, is not what you are asking about, because once you move from Dedekind-finite set of reals to a Dedekind-infinite set of reals you invariably add new reals.

In a conversation with Woodin about a month ago, I mentioned this result, and he told me that some 30 years ago he proved the following (and never published it):

> For any regular uncountable $\kappa$, $L(\Bbb R)^{L^{\operatorname{Add}(\omega,\kappa)}}$ is the same. In particular, if you start with $L$, add $\omega_1$ Cohen reals, consider $L(\Bbb R)$ [which is a model of $\sf DC$], you can recover choice without adding reals by ordering $\Bbb R$ in however way you like it to be ordered.

This means that you have a plethora of various models with the same ordinals, cofinalities, and reals, but in different models you have different reals. Which is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks to Andres for leaving a comment on the now-deleted answer. It reminded me of the relevant result.

Comment: Asaf, what do you mean here by $\mathrm{Add}(\omega,\kappa)$? Adding a $\kappa$-Cohen set ($\mathrm{Add}(\kappa,1)$), or adding $\kappa$ Cohen reals? (Presumably the former.)

Comment: The latter, of course.

Comment: And, by latter, you meant former...

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry, I just woke up! :-)

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused about the whole comments thread.